# Query in Google Sheets WHERE and OR

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write a query to combine data from two sheets with same heading where data in first column is either a date or a specific string.
Example
`=query({Sheet1!A:B;, Sheet2!A2:B}, "select * where Col1 > date 'YYYY-MM-DD' OR Col1 = 'example string' ")`

The values are reflecting for date but not for the example string.
The example string entered for Col1 in the formula, is selected from a pulldown list in sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

better try:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A:B; Sheet2!A2:B}, 
 ({Sheet1!A:A; Sheet2!A2:A}>"01/01/2000")+({Sheet1!A:A; Sheet2!A2:A}="example text"))
```